# Open pyqt program without console with pythonw

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pywin32

i have a strange problem. I created a GUI program which runs in `"spyder"` with `WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.3` with no problems, now i want to run it without the console to pop up and i try to use `pythonw.exe`.

When i save my GUI as `gui.pyw` i can open it with `PythonWin` by right clicking and use `edit with PythonWin` but simply double-clicking will make my GUI pop up for less than a second and exit the program afterwards.

Does this have to do with my GUI programming?
the "structure" is this one:

```
import sys 
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, Qt  
from Main_Window_v2 import Ui_Dialog as Dlg

class MeinDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Dlg): 
    def __init__(self): 
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self) 
        self.setupUi(self)
    
  
        self.connect(self.buttonOK, 
            QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onOK) 
        self.connect(self.buttonAbbrechen, 
            QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onClose)                  
        self.connect(self.buttonsql, 
            QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onsql)

    def onsql(self):
   
        login=self.login_text_box.toPlainText()
   
        from calc import get_variables #sql query
        self.get_variables=get_variables(login)
        #calls a class´ __init__ in another file in my direcotry

    
    def onOK(self):
        login=self.login_text_box.toPlainText()

        self.get_variables.plot(login)
        #calls another function in my class "calc"
    def onClose(self): 
        print("bye!")
        self.close()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
dialog = MeinDialog() 
dialog.show()
```

I also tried to get an `.exe` using `cx_freeze` and after trying to making build as described here [Cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html): I have the same problem: The Main-Window of the GUI
pops up and disappears again

Comment: Don't you have `app.exec_()` at the end of your code?

Comment: oh yes, you are totally right- and guess what... it works now :)

Comment: Ok, I'll put that in an answer, accept it if you like :)

Comment: `cx_freeze` still has the same problem after rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `app.exec_()` at the end of your code. Your code was running well in Spyder because Spyder uses PyQt and had the main loop of events already running.

Answer (score 0):

You should add app.exex_() at the end of your code, it is used to dispatch all PyQt GUI threads message or other threads info message.